# how can i fix a broken links and blocked folder in cpanel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, cpanel, public-html

I have (style folder) in my public_html.
in the style folder i have:

style
-- css
---- main
---- services
---- contact

-- js
---- contact

-- images 
---- contact

i a have a problem when i access to any file in the (( contact folder )) :
https://example.com/style/css/contact/contact.css
OR
https://example.com/style/js/contact/contact.js
OR
https://example.com/style/images/contact/contact.png

all links are loading all time and not open.
all folders have 755
and files have 644

but all files and folders worked successfully without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

use {{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}